# AWS Application Load Balancer redirect all www and non http to https://

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a rule setup to redirect all traffic from http to https

[image]

How can I also redirect http://www to https://? As far as I can tell the {host} variable contains www and I cant remove it.

Comment: What is your architecture? Are you using CloudFront and/or Route 53?

Comment: How many domains point to the ELB?

Comment: multiple domains are on the ELB and im using Route 53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's pretty simple
Instead of writing `{host}` in your rule just put the name of your website.
So, for example, it will look like this :
`https://example.com:443/#{path}?#{query}`